# what happens to a modified file merged during pull and then reverted

Tags: git

I've modified a file `some.txt` but have not committed it. I make `git pull` which fetches and merges changes. Someone on the other end modified `some.txt` and git detects a merge conflict. I resolve the conflict using my copy. Then I decide to revert changes. My question is whether `some.txt` will be in the state it was before I started to modify it or in the state which it would have if I resolved using remote copy?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have resolved all conflicts then it will be in the state of remote copy. Here I have some suggestions like :-

1. When you get conflicts in git pull then first save copy of your changes at some place.
2. Use git reset --hard
3. Use git pull
4. Now, patch your changes to the new repository.
5. Commit your new changes to the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

You should always `git commit` your changes before you do a `git pull` for exactly this reason. 
Since you are using only working directory files, which aren't versioned, there is nothing to go back to.